# SASS: Inheriting set variable from parent in mixin

Tags: css, variables, inheritance, sass

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/northproject/Cm7NR/) to demonstrate this issue. It's just an example.

**What I'm doing**

Let's say I'm making a flexible grid. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>
    <p>d</p>
</div>
```

Four columns. I have two mixins and a global variable called **$gutter**. In my mixin, I call this variable to add gutters and change the widths.

```
$gutter: 1%;

@mixin col($width){
    float: left;
    width: $width - ($gutter * 2);
    margin: 0 $gutter;
}
@mixin row(){
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I use it like so:

```
div { @include row(); }
p { @include col(25%); }
```

**What I want to do**

Now let's say I want to add a second, different grid to the page. I create this HTML and give each grid and ID to differentiate them:

```
<div id="one">
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>
    <p>d</p>
</div>

<div id="two">
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>
    <p>d</p>
</div>​
```

*I want the second grid to have a different gutter width. Or, alternatively, no gutters.*

```
#one { @include row(); }
#two { @include row($gutter: 0); }
```

This obviously does not work. Because the number of columns can be variable, I cannot add this $gutter:0 declaration to each instance of @include col(). It breaks the DRY principle and eventually (in complicated layouts) becomes unmaintainable.

**The question**

How can I allow a variable set in one mixin to filter down to another (on a child element)? I am aware that I could simply do this:

```
@mixin row(){
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    .col { etc etc etc }
}
```

But the class name may not always be *.col*. Does this make sense? **I want the col() mixin to inherit a variable I pass through to the row() mixin.** How?

Comment: So this soultion: http://jsfiddle.net/Cm7NR/2/ will doesn't work for you? Instead of taking class name I used a tag which will be used only inside element where mixin is included.

Comment: This won't really work. It will not always be a single tag, and your method doesn't allow for separate setting of column width.

Answer (score 1):

I forked the jsfiddle from Sófka and extended it with the CSS Child selector (">") to target any tags in the row.

```
// Inside the row mixin
& > * {
    @include col($columnWidth, $gutter);
}
```

Furthermore I added the column width attribute to the mixin and set a default gutter.

```
$defaultGutter: 1% !default; // Make sure the variable is set
@mixin col($width, $gutter: $defaultGutter){
    ...
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/N44LW/12/

PS.:I'm not sure if I fully understood your question, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: I was looking for `& * {}` nice call.